# How to sort this array of hashmaps prpoerly

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, data-structures

So, I'm having issues trying to understand how to sort this array of hashmaps properly.
Data:

```js
let array = 
    [ { name               : 'John'  } 
    , { species            : 'Human' } 
    , { species_sort_order : '1'     } 
    , { name_sort_order    : '2'     } 
    , { species            : 'Dog'   } 
    , { name               : 'oreo'  } 
    , { species_sort_order : ''      } 
    , { name_sort_order    : '1'     } 
    , { name_sort_order    : ''      } 
    , { name               : 'Susan' } 
    , { species            : 'Human' } 
    , { species_sort_order : ''      } 
   // , ... and so on
    ]
```

**1) So there are 4 key value pairs:**

- name,
- Species,
- name_sort_order,
- species_sort_order

**2) The related values will appear next to each other; however, they can be in random order as shown above and below:**

- `{name: "John"}, {species: "Human"}, {species_sort_order: "1"}, {name_sort_order: "2"}`
- `{species_sort_order: "1"}, {species: "Human"}, {name_sort_order: "2"}, {name: "John"}`
- `{species: "Human"}, {species_sort_order: "1"}, {name: "John"}, {name_sort_order: "2"}`

**3) If a sort_order value is an empty string ("") then it doesn't have a sorting position and it's placement is irrelevant.**

**4) The desired output would resemble the below**

```html
<h2>Human</h2>
<ul>
  <li>John</li>
  <li>Susan</li>
</ul>
<h2>Dog</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Oreo</li>
</ul>
```

This is already a wordy post; so, I won't list all of my attempts, but also, I'm not looking for someone to give me the code for this (although you can if you want), I'm a fan of data structure and algorithm problems... but this isn't some fun coding problem, it has real world implications so I'm just looking to see if anyone has any good strategies.

So far, my thought process is:

1)

```
// Iterate through the list of hashmaps,
// if the index is dividable by 3 (i%3),
//     then push empty array
//     push hashmap to the last array in the array (e.g. ar[ar.length-1].push(hashmap))
// otherwise
//      push hashmap to the last array in the array (e.g. ar[ar.length-1].push(hashmap))
```

2. Now I have an array of arrays, where each array contains the related hashmap values.
   So, my next thought process is to start sorting the array in the order of

- A) species_sort_order then
- B) name_sort_order... but this has become a very costly algorithm as
  far as time complexity and just doesn't seem efficient.

EDIT:
I know the original input (array of objects) makes this more difficult than it needs to be; but that's the data returned from an AJAX response.

I can't use any external libraries, only JavaScript and it's inbuilt functions

Comment: This question makes me wonder why your array of objects is the way it is.  It puts properties that belong to the same object on separate objects which makes it a lot harder to keep things together when you sort.  I'd say fix whatever generates this data first.  Then, the sorting will be trivial.

Comment: can `species_sort_order` and `name_sort_order` have letters value, and can't be changed to integer values ( or float values?) ?

Comment: @jfriend00  I know the original input (array of objects) makes this more difficult than it needs to be; but that's the data returned from the AJAX response.

Comment: @MisterJojo no, they can only have integers in string format or an empty string. You can definitely do a parseInt() to transform the "1" into a 1

Comment: The logic for keys order is unclear. Looking at your HTML output, Human-John` have keys values of `1-2`, `Dog-oreo` ->  `empty-2` and `Human-Susan` -> `empty-empty`. As `Dog` come before `Susan` and both of them have and empy key for species_sort_order. Your explanation indicates that their reciprocal order remains unchanged, which breaks the species grouping. If we sort first on `species` then then on `species_sort_order` the grouping is preserved, but in this case `species:'Dog'` comes before` species:'Human'` which is not not no longer the case in your html output.

Comment: @MisterJojo the tag_sort_order only affects tags that are in the same species. The "Human" species has a sort order of 2, Dog has no sort order. No matter what human will come before dog. There's no way Dog can come before Human.

Comment: I don't understand why Susan, with no `species_sort_order` associated, would come before `dog`.  Is there some additional grouping you want to do as well as the sorting?  And if so, when Susan and John have different `species_sort_order`s associated, how do we choose which one would win?

Answer (score 1):

I think lodash might be a good way to achieved it

```
const arr = [ {name: "John"}, {species: "Human"}, {species_sort_order: "1"}, {name_sort_order: "2"},
      {species: "Dog"}, {name: "oreo"}, {species_sort_order: ""}, {name_sort_order: "1"}, 
      {name_sort_order: ""}, {name: "Susan"}, {species: "Human"}, {species_sort_order: ""}]
    
_.orderBy(arr, ['name', 'species'], ['asc', 'asc'])
```

Comment: My bad, I should've noted that  I can't use any external libraries, only JavaScript and it's inbuilt functions

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like a homework problem

Comment: @Hive7 lol I majored in computer science and I have atteneded a full stack bootcamp... trust me, ain't no school ask problems this difficult! This is real world, it's coming in as a response due to an AJAX request.

Comment: That doesn't seem to address the grouping required.

Answer (score 1):

as far from what I can do ...

```js
const keyS = (str,lg) => ((str||'') + ' '.repeat(lg)).substring(0, lg)
const keyN = (num,def,mask) => (!num) ? ((!def) ? '9'.repeat(mask.length) : `${mask}${def}`.slice(-mask.length)) : `${mask}${num}`.slice(-mask.length)

const data = 
  [ { name               : 'John'  } 
  , { species            : 'Human' } 
  , { species_sort_order : '1'     } 
  , { name_sort_order    : '2'     }
  , { species            : 'Dog'   } 
  , { name               : 'oreo'  } 
  , { species_sort_order : ''      } 
  , { name_sort_order    : '1'     }
  , { name_sort_order    : ''      } 
  , { name               : 'Susan' } 
  , { species            : 'Human' } 
  , { species_sort_order : ''      } 
  // , ... and so on
  ] 


, dataOrd = data.reduce((a,c,i,{[i+1]:next})=>
  {
  let ref = i%4, pos = Math.floor(i/4);
  if (!ref ) a.r.push({...c})
  else       a.r[pos] = {...a.r[pos],...c}    // group 4 by 4 objects

  if (ref===3) // === last item of 4
    {
    let grp = a.r[pos]
    a.nso = Math.max( a.nso, (grp.name_sort_order    || 0))  // get max
    a.sso = Math.max( a.sso, (grp.species_sort_order || 0)) // values &
    a.sLg = Math.max( a.sLg, (grp.species || '').length)   // max length

    if (grp.species_sort_order != '')             // memorize sort orders
      a.sKeys[grp.species] = grp.species_sort_order; // by species names
    }

  if (!!next) return a  // still in reduce loop
  else   // no next element -> reduce loop final              
    {
    let nsoMask = '0'.repeat( (++a.nso).toString(10).length)  // keys
      , ssoMask = '0'.repeat( (++a.sso).toString(10).length) // mask buiders
      ;
    a.r.forEach(({species, species_sort_order, name, name_sort_order},i,t) =>
        {
        t[i].key = keyN( species_sort_order, a.sKeys[species], ssoMask )
                + keyS( species, a.sLg )
                + keyN( name_sort_order, '', nsoMask )
        })
    a.r.sort((o1, o2) => o1.key.localeCompare(o2.key))

    // console.log(JSON.stringify(a,0,2))
    return a.r
    }
  },{ r:[], nso:0, sso:0, sLg:0, sKeys:{} })

// displaying HTML result
const divOutPut = document.querySelector('div#outPut')
let speciesGrp = ''
  , speciesElm = null
  , ulGrp      = null
  , liElm      = null

dataOrd.forEach(({species, name}) => 
  {
  if (speciesGrp != species)
    {
    speciesElm = divOutPut.appendChild(document.createElement('h2'))
    ulGrp      = divOutPut.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'))
    speciesElm.textContent = speciesGrp = species
    }
  liElm             = ulGrp.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
  liElm.textContent = name
  })
```

```html
<div id="outPut"></div>
```

Comment: @ezg I spent time to develop this answer, I would have liked to have at least one comment...

Comment: @ezg this is not only a place for just questions and answers, it is also a place for sharing where the Netiquette also applies  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiquette_in_technology#Netiquette

Answer (score 1):

By making a potentially invalid guess about the real sorting requirements, which still seem fuzzy in light of the potential empty string values, I can come up with this:

```js
// utility functions
const chunk = (n) => (xs) =>
  xs .length <= n ? [[...xs]] : [xs .slice (0, n), ... chunk (n) (xs .slice (n))]

const group = (fn) => (xs) =>
  Object .values (xs .reduce (
    (a, x) => ({...a, [fn(x)]: [...(a[fn(x)] || []), x]}),
    {}
  ))


// helper function
const makeRecords = (xs) =>
  chunk (4) (xs) .map (gs => Object .assign (...gs))


// main function
const restructure = (array) => group ((x) => x.species) (makeRecords (array))
  .sort (([{species_sort_order: s1}], [{species_sort_order: s2}]) => (s1 || Infinity) - (s2 || Infinity))
  .map (s => s.sort (({name_sort_order: n1}, {name_sort_order: n2}) => (n1 || Infinity) - (n2 || Infinity)))


// sample data
const array = [{name: "John"}, {species: "Human"}, {species_sort_order: "1"}, {name_sort_order: "2"}, {species: "Dog"}, {name: "oreo"}, {species_sort_order: ""}, {name_sort_order: "1"}, {name_sort_order: ""}, {name: "Susan"}, {species: "Human"}, {species_sort_order: ""}]


// demo
const results = restructure (array)

document .getElementById ('output') .innerHTML = results .map (xs => `<h2>${xs[0].species}</h2><ul>${xs.map(x => `<li>${x.name}</li>`).join('')}</ul>`).join('')
document .getElementById ('result') .innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(results, null, 4)}</pre>`
```

```html
<div id="output"></div><hr/><h3>Transformed data</h1><pre id="result"></pre>
```

We start with two utility functions:

- **`chunk`** breaks an array into `n`-long subarrays (with the final one possibly shorter.)

  ```js
  chunk (3) ([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9])  //=> [[8, 6, 7], [5, 3, 0], [9]]`
  ```
- **`group`** takes a string/number returning function and an array of values, grouping the values into subarrays with the same result on applying the function.

  ```js
  group (n => n % 10) ([23, 12, 16, 33, 3, 42])
  //=> [[12, 42], [23, 33, 3], [16]]
  ``
  ```

Then we have a single helper function:

- **`makeRecords`** takes an array of your input items, chunks them into groups of four and combines the result into items that look like this:

  ```js
  {
      name: "John",
      species: "Human",
      species_sort_order: "1",
      name_sort_order: "2"
  }
  ```

Then our main function:

- **`restructure`** takes your input, turns it into records with `makeRecords`, calls `group` to group these by species, then sorts the species according to the first `species_sort_order` in each group, and sorts the groups internally by their `name_sort_order`s.

An assumption here is that the items without sort keys can just be placed at the end of their group, in arbitrary order.  A second one is that we can use the first record in each group to choose how to sort the groups.  This is what I thought might be unwarranted.  But if there is a different requirement, it should probably be spelled out in more detail, with a more complete example.

---

A comment suggested that this problem is way too difficult for a school assignment.  It's not.  I've received and given much more challenging ones.  If you break this down into small parts that do one job well, it's fairly easy to break this into steps.

In that vein, I might suggest a tweak to `group`, using two additional functions, `push` that pushes a value to an array and returns the array, and `set` that sets the value of a property on an object.  Generally, I prefer to avoid mutating data, but there is an exception for data internal to a function, and here it can avoid a [potential performance problem](https://www.richsnapp.com/article/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern).  So we might write it like this instead:

```js
const push = (x) => (xs = []) =>
  ((xs .push (x)), xs)

const set = (v) => (k) => (o = {}) =>
  ((o[k] = v), o)

const group = (fn) => (xs) =>
  Object .values (xs .reduce (
    (a, x) => set (push (x) (a [fn (x)])) (fn(x)) (a),
    {}
  ))
```